# IF Statement using IF, OR, AND with multiple logics ERROR

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I am trying to write a formula based on the following conditions and it is not working

- IF A1 = "S", and B1 = 254 or 127, Use LIST NOLIST
- IF A1 = "F" or "M", and B1 = 254, and C1 is even, Use LIST EVEN254
- IF A1 = "F" or "M", and B1 = 254, and C1 is odd, use LIST ODD254
- IF A1 = "F" or "M", and B1 = 127, and C1 is even, Use LIST EVEN127
- IF A1 = "F" or "M", and B1 = 254, and C1 is odd, use LIST ODD127

Here's the formula I am currently using. I am receiving an #VALUE error

=IF(OR(AND(B1=127,B1=254),AND(A1="S")),NOLIST,IF(OR(AND(A1="F",A1="M"),AND(B1=127,C1="T")),EVEN127,IF(OR(AND(A1="F",A1="M"),AND(B1=127,C1="F")),ODD127,IF(OR(AND(A1="F",A1="M"),AND(B1=254,C1="T")),EVEN254,IF(OR(AND(A1="F",A1="M"),AND(B1=254,C1="F")),ODD254,"")))))

I also tried this which did not work either

=IF(AND(B1=254,C1="T",OR(A1="F",A1="M")),EVEN254,IF(AND(B1=254,C1="F",OR(A1="F",A1="M")),ODD254,IF(AND(B1=127,C1="T",OR(A1="F",A1="M")),EVEC127,IF(AND(B1=127,C1="F",OR(A1="F",A1="M")),ODD127,IF(AND(B1=254,B1=127),OR(A1="S")),NOLIST,""))))

My initial formula was working, and then I realized I had to add the conditions for the ODD/EVEN numbers so after I added those conditions to the formula, it stopped working.
Here's my original formula

=IF(OR(AND(B1=127,B1=254),AND(A1="S")),NOLIST,IF(OR(AND(A1="F",A1="M"),AND(B1=127)),EVEN127,IF(OR(AND(A1="F",A1="M"),AND(B1=254)),EVEN254,"")))

I changed the list names for simplicity, so the original list names did not contain even/odd.

Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: First replace OR(AND(B1=127,B1=254),AND(A1="S")) with AND(OR(B1=127,B1=254)),A1="S") then recheck the rest of your expression. I would build it section by section though.

Comment: I tried that and it still didn't work. Thank you, though!

Comment: Can you see the difference between your first test and what I suggested?

Comment: I rewrote the formula and I am receiving the error there is a problem with this formula once I hit enter. Her's the formula for example. =IF(AND(OR($B$8=127,$B$8=254)),$M$1="S"),NOLIST,IF(AND(OR($M$1="F",$M$1="M")),$B$8=127,JC!B4="T"),HOUSING127,IF(AND(OR($M$1="F",$M$1="M")),$B$8=127,JC!B4="F"),ODDH127,IF(AND(OR($M$1="F",$M$1="M")),B8=254,JC!B4="T"),HOUSING254,IF(AND(OR($M$1="F",$M$1="M")),B8=254,JC!B4="F"),ODDH254,"")))))

Answer (score 1):

If you use indentation and array constants, it's a bit easier to sort this out:

I have assumed your last clause is incorrect though, you write:

- `IF A1 = "F" or "M", and B1 = 254, and C1 is odd, use LIST ODD127`

  - *I assume that you meant* `B1=127`
- I used strings for testing. Perhaps you meant to use named ranges?  But I'm not sure since `ODD127` and `ODD254` are not allowed names for a named reference in Excel 2007+
- If one of the allowed combinations is not present, the formula will return `FALSE`.

```
=IF(AND(A1="S",OR(B1={254,127})),"NOLIST",
  IF(OR(A1={"F","M"}),
       IF(B1=254,
            IF(ISEVEN(C1),"EVEN254","ODD254"),
      IF(B1=127,
            IF(ISEVEN(C1),"EVEN127","ODD127")))))
```

If, as you noted in a comment, this is being used to generate a list for Data Validation, then you cannot use the array constants.  Merely substitute the form that does not use the array constants:

```
=IF(AND(A1="S",OR(B1=254,B1=127)),"NOLIST",
  IF(OR(A1="F",A1="M"),
       IF(B1=254,
            IF(ISEVEN(C1),"EVEN254","ODD254"),
      IF(B1=127,
            IF(ISEVEN(C1),"EVEN127","ODD127")))))
```

And you can replace the strings in the above formulas with the real names of the named ranges you wish to see.

Comment: I did not know you could do OR(A1={"F","M"}).  I always used OR(A1="F",A1="M").  And it was god awful the more OR options their were!  Thank you for opening my eyes to this possibility!

Comment: @ForwardEd that is a trick that works for many functions in similar situations, but good to see it again.

Comment: Hi,  thank you for your help! The formula returned no errors when entering regularly, but what I forgot to mention is that I'm putting it into the data validation. The names "EVEN254" are drop-down lists to pull from, and it says that arrays are not ale to be used in conditional formatting.

Comment: @d87 Yes, it is always best to provide needed information, otherwise you will get an answer that doesn't address your real problem. ODD127 is still not a valid Named Range, but you can replace the test strings with the **actual** names. And if you are using the formula in Data validation, why not just change the sections that use the array constants into formulas that don't. eg: instead of OR(A1={"F","M"}) use =OR(A1="F",A1="M") and similarly with the other clauses that use array constants.  And I've edited the answer to show that.